# PyCharm does not recognise installed module

Tags: python, numpy, package, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

The code was working without any isses. Suddently Pycharm return ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'. The same error appears for the other pachages as well.

My iterpreter has given pachages added.

[Interpreter Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/825Mz.png)

I also made sure to update the version of the matplotlib and numpy in the terminal. Yet it makes no difference as well.

Comment: Are you using the "Run" button? If so, check your run configuration with "Edit Configurations" and make sure you have your project-default interpreter selected.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the version of 'matplotlib' installed is not compatible with your code. In PyCharm, go to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Project" -> "Python Interpreter," select the package in question, and ensure that it is the correct version. You can also try specifying a particular version of 'matplotlib' by using the command:

pip install matplotlib==<version_number>

Comment: I included a picture of "File" -> "Settings" -> "Project" -> "Python Interpreter" page in the question. I don't think that's the problem